# Take screenshot of a video stream I am not watching

Tags: android, linux, telnet, vlc, snapshot

I am doing an android application where I want to show a screenshot of a video stream I am not receiving in order for the user to decide if he is going to switch or not to that stream.

I am using VLC to stream the videos and VLC remote control interface to control it via telnet and command it to take **snapshot**s but I can't do a snapshot of a video I am not watching,

is there a way around this?

Comment: I am not watching mean, that application running in background, in such case,from RTSP Stream can't you take the buffer and create RGB or YUV Image ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, libVLC requires the video stream to be "active" when using its snapshot feature (as far as I see when using VLCJ's `saveSnapshot(file)` method implementation - it says `save a snapshot of the currently playing video`). So, in your case, it is not possible if you don't play the video yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it but i have to be receiving the stream as [ee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311777/ee) said, thanks :)

```
cvlc $CHANNEL_URL --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --aout=dummy --scene-format=$FORMAT --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=$PREFIX --scene-path=$SNAPSHOT_PATH --scene-width=$WIDTH --scene-replace vlc://quit &
```

Comment: How to do this? I am getting stream but how to pass this command to LibVlc, did not understand can u give me some sample of code?